# retaining Likes while moving to https - og:url getting rewritten

Tags: facebook, https, facebook-like

I am moving from http to https. I accumulated 5K likes over the years and want to retain them. As mentioned in several places, you need to do a 301 redirect, plus as per facebook's instructions: "Add an og:url tag to the new URL which points at the old URL" (from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#moving-urls)

The problem is, when I have FB scrape the page, it changes my og:url!

Scrape results:
Based on the raw tags, we constructed the following Open Graph properties
og:url  https://www.mybirthdayfacts.com/

Raw tag it read:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mybirthdayfacts.com" />
```

So how can we get our likes back when the scraper changes your og:url? Has anyone seen this problem before? I've seen posts where people seem to have done this successfully, not sure where I went wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to _not_ redirect the Facebook scraper, it needs to be able to still access the old HTTP URL and fetch the meta data from there.

Comment: But if I'm just changing from http to https, and there's a 301 redirect from http to https, then the old URL is not accessible. I end up with a circular redirect error from FB.

Comment: Thats why you need to _not_ redirect the Facebook scraper, you will need to implement an exception for it (can be identified by the User-Agent it sends.)

Comment: Not sure I can do that with my shared windows hosting plan. But I give up. I use the graph api to grab the counts from the http and https versions of my site, add them, and display the total myself. Lame, but I'm tired of messing with this nonsense - with the big push towards https, you would think FB would make this painless :( Anyway, thank you very much for your suggestions!